# Basic Home Plumbing Diagram Question

Tags: plumbing

Would appreciate if someone could give feedback on this basic plumbing set up diagram.  I realize I should add a bypass around the Filter and the Tankless already has shut off valves on both the hot and cold.  The main water service lines are 1" all the way through and are 1/2" distribution to the house.

Any other comments or critiques?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty basic, looks fine. Note that there will usually be more outlets on the cold manifold.

To the extent (not much) that it makes any difference I prefer to put hose spigots and toilets at the far end of the manifold, and showers at the end closest to the input of both manifolds.

Comment: Appreciate that (yes the drawing doesn't reflect the actual number of runs).  Is your preference for ordering of outlets based on having more pressure nearer the input?  Do you have a manifold preference (Pex A)?